# Checking for duplicate records in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working in a project and I have member enrolment section to insert users in my table. But I don't want to insert same data to my table. For this, I have a function to control duplicated members.

It is working, however there is another problem. If another insert with same data is issued before my first transaction is finished both transaction succeed.  So I have two database records with the same member data.

How can I write my function check it and prevent same member to be recorded ın database

Comment: I am not sure if there is word named `Doublicated` ;)

Comment: Checkıng Double Member ?

Comment: Do you mean duplicates? You want to remove duplicates and avoid them in future?

Comment: for example I want to record a member to database but ı dont want, same person ıs recorded again  into db

Comment: and I check ıt wıth a fuctıon, and it runs true

Comment: however there is another problem

Comment: You can make the column as unique in your table.

Comment: if same data wıll be sent ın miliseconds, then both of datas whıch are same, recoreded ın db

Comment: What do you mean by 'sent in miliseconds', are you refering to a column that has a timestamp?

Comment: I didnt know the reason actually

Comment: Normally my isDoubleMemberBySource(.....) functıon dont allow to record same data

Comment: however when tester team, sent same data, they say that both of data ıs recorded ın db

Comment: Therefore I thınk that before my fırst member ıs recorded ın db, maybe another member enter data and because db dont have same data stıll, ıt allow

Comment: ı am not sure but, and maybe my ıdea ıs wrong

Comment: Why don't you simply create a unique index on that column? Then handle the errors from that properly. And I don't see the reason for using a stored procedure here.

Comment: Can you post the function?

Comment: use a 'before insert' trigger to verify if the member is already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating Unique Constraint?

Comment: Yes ıt can be a solutıon but ıt conflıg wıth another ıssues, I suggest thıs solutıon but my team member doesnt accept ıt::)) and I try to fınd another way

Comment: If he does not accept, he probably has a better business class solution in mind :) he can share

Comment: how about use mutex ın oracle

Comment: ıf ı use DBMS_LOCK ,then  maybe ı can lock my sessıon and dont allow other transactıon untıll the fırst sessıon ıs done

Comment: There is no mutex you can manage (maybe you can use context instead, still complicated) and lock management causes issues.

Comment: Sure if you implement any locking/checking mechanism it may work. And all depends on your business, load and concurrency. I just find  constraints an easy and powerful solution for maintaining data integrity/consistency.

Answer (score 0):

The only correct solution is to create a unique constraint on the MEMBER table, choosing some business key.

Unique constraints operate at the database internal level, and so performs way better than any code we write ourselves.  Hand-crafted checks just won't scale in the same way.   Also constraints are guaranteed to enforce uniqueness in multi-user environments.

Whereas, as you've discovered, code we write ourselves does not.  This is because Oracle's Read Consistency means that uncommitted changes in session 1 are invisible to session 2; so regardless of what checks session 2 makes, it will insert the duplicate record because its version is the only version it can see.

Also, it is easy to avoid invoking our own code, by writing one-off insert statements, or by writing an update statements.  We cannot avoid unique constraints: we can drop or disable them, but that's a concious decision.

In short, databases which rely on application code to enforce uniqueness or relation integrity *inevitably* end up with data corruption.